# Convert Gaussian Like Histogram into Uniform Analytically

Tags: image-processing, transfer-function, histogram

If I have the histogram of an input image as Gaussian probability density function of the form:

$$P_r(r)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\dfrac{(r-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$

where: $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the mean and standard deviation of the Gaussian PDF respectively.

The approach is to let $\mu$ and $\sigma$ be the measures of average grey level and contrast of a given image. What is the transformation function that can be used for histogram equalization?

Now, I found that I have to take small value for sigma and make some integration. So any help to do that please?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to have a theoretical solution?  There are *lots* of numerical techniques for accomplishing this, and that should be sufficient for any real application.

Comment: any techniques would you advise me to use?@John

Comment: You may look at the derivation in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/61098.

Comment: A detailed derivation is also available at https://www.math.uci.edu/icamp/courses/math77c/demos/hist_eq.pdf.

Comment: You may look into methods to convert Uniform PDF to Gaussian. Basically you're after the inverse.