# The Math of Histogram Matching

Tags: image-processing, math, self-study, histogram, enhancement

Please help solve the problem in the picture. I am confused due to the piecewise nature of the density functions. If it was a simple curved PDF, I would simply integrate over full range and use the single CDF expressions. But, for this piecewise case, in each section I will have different expressions.

P.S.--This is NOT a homework question. It is from a past year exam.
[image]

Comment: The PDFs are NOT discrete, just defined as sections. They are continuous and easy to ingrate.  You just have to do it piecewise

Comment: I apologize. I misspoke. I knew it was continuous, I meant to say one simple curve. I have edited the post.
Anyway, how do I solve for this piecewise case? I have to find expressions of CDF with respect to 'r' and 'z'. But, in each section i will have different expressions.

Comment: A piecewise problem typically has a piecewise solution: solve for each section individually and than splice them together.

Comment: For example the CDF of $\int p_r(r) = 4/5\cdot r - 1/5 \cdot r^2, 0 < r < 1$ and $ 3/5 + 2/5(r-1), 1 < r < 2 $

Comment: I can find the cdf for each section. My question is about histogram matching. Do I also do the histogram matching for each section separately ? 
Like, do I compute one transformation for interval 0<r,z<1 and another different expression for 1< r,z <2 ?

Comment: Related to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/61098.

Comment: Related to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18098.

Answer (score 1):

The steps are as following:

1. Calculate the CDF of each PDF: $ {p}_{r} \left( r \right ) \rightarrow {P}_{r} \left( r \right ), \; {p}_{z} \left( z \right ) \rightarrow {P}_{z} \left( z \right ) $.
2. Map $ r \to {P}_{z}^{-1} \left( {P}_{r} \left( r \right ) \right) $.

#### The CDF

You functions are piece wise linear:

$$ {p}_{r} \left( r \right) = \begin{cases} -\frac{2}{5} r + \frac{4}{5} & \text{ if } 0 \leq r \leq 1 \\ \frac{2}{5} & \text{ if } 1 < r \leq 2 \end{cases} \rightarrow {P}_{r} \left( r \right) = \begin{cases} -\frac{1}{5} {r}^{2} + \frac{4}{5} r & \text{ if } 0 \leq r \leq 1 \\ \frac{2}{5} \left( r - 1 \right) + \frac{3}{5} & \text{ if } 1 < r \leq 2 \end{cases} $$

$$ {p}_{z} \left( z \right) = \begin{cases} \frac{2}{5} & \text{ if } 0 \leq z \leq 1 \\ \frac{2}{5} z & \text{ if } 1 < z \leq 2 \end{cases} \rightarrow {P}_{z} \left( z \right) = \begin{cases} \frac{2}{5} z & \text{ if } 0 \leq z \leq 1 \\ \frac{1}{5} {\left( z - 1 \right)}^{2} + \frac{2}{5} & \text{ if } 1 < z \leq 2 \end{cases} $$

### The Inverse Function

The inverse function of $ {P}_{z} \left( z \right) $ is given by:

$$ {P}_{z}^{-1} \left( t \right) = \begin{cases} \frac{5}{2} t & \text{ if } 0 \leq t \leq 1 \\ \sqrt{5 \left( t - \frac{2}{5} \right)} + 1 & \text{ if } 1 < t \leq 2 \end{cases} $$

Now all needed is to compose the functions.

For reference you may use [Wikipedia - Histogram Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching).